# How to create a ::before for multiple #id

Tags: css

Is it possible to insert multiple id in a before?

I have:

```
#ps4 ::before {
  [...]
}
#ps3 ::before {
  [...]
}
```

i tried with `#ps4, #ps3 ::before` but nothing, is it possible to insert more #id for a before? I would like to keep the css as clean and short as possible...

I tried looking at css-trick but I couldn't find anything explaining how to create a before for multiple id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `:is()`

```css
:is(#ps4,#ps3)::before {
  content:"OK";
}
```

```html
<div id="ps4"></div>
<div id="ps3"></div>
```